# Habilitar HTTPS no Amazon Beanstalk em aplicação Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-aws, https, elastic-beanstalk

Estou encontrando dificuldade para conseguir habilitar o **HTTPS** num aplicativo na **Amazon Beanstalk** em **single instance**.

O aplicativo é desenvolvido em Java (Spring Boot), com tomcat embedado e para implantação utilizei o arquivo **.jar** gerado. O aplicativo está funcional e já foi adicionado um domínio. Na porta http está funcionando perfeitamente.

Solicitei e já está disponível um certificado atrelado ao domínio correspondente pelo console da amazon em "Certificate Manager".

Pelos tutoriais me parece que quando a instância utiliza o load balance a Amazon simplifica a utilização do certificado gerado, contudo o aplicativo está usando uma única instância, para este caso os manuais instruem à habilitação via arquivos de configuração, e é nesta parte que eu estou "emperrado".

Tentei seguir os seguintes tutoriais:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-java.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-tomcat.html

Contudo não sei exatamente se devo criar ou editar arquivos e diretórios e onde, sobretudo porque no S3 da aplicação tenho a seguinte arquitetura.

[image: S3 da aplicação]

Em resumo peço ajuda para **configurar minha aplicação para aceitar receber requisições https** utilizando o certificado gerado na amazon.

Grato.

Answer (score 2):

De fato, parece que não é muito óbvio como fazer isto com o Spring Boot.

> Contudo não sei exatamente se devo criar ou editar arquivos e
>   diretórios e onde, sobretudo porque no S3 da aplicação tenho a
>   seguinte arquitetura.

Vai dentro da raiz do JAR do Spring Boot.

Parece que a [forma mais simples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44715929/2387977) de fazer isto é por Maven.

Adicione o `.ebextensions` na raiz do seu projeto e adicione o seguinte plugin ao final dos `plugins` do pom.xml do seu projeto:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <unzip src="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar" dest="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}" />
                            <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/" overwrite="false">
                                <fileset dir="./" includes=".ebextensions/**"/>
                            </copy>
                            <zip compress="false" destfile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar" basedir="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}"/>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Este plugin vai usar o ant para descompactar o JAR final do Spring Boot, copiar o `.ebextensions` na raiz do conteúdo do JAR, compactar o conteúdo em um novo JAR com o mesmo nome do original.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Esse procedimento não teria como resultado final a criação do diretório na raiz do local onde o app foi implantado?

Comment: Seria diferente de criar o diretório .ebextensions no console da AWS manualmente?

Comment: @DuilioBenjoino, para a primeira pergunta, entendo que não. Pelo que li na documentação, precisa estar dentro do JAR/WAR mesmo. Recomendo fazer um teste e ver se dá certo.

Comment: Estou tentando efetuar o teste mais ainda encontro dificuldades em criar os arquivos corretamente, sobretudo o arquivo que precisa dos dados do certificado. É possível utilizar o certificado gerado pela AWS nesse esquema?

Comment: @DuilioBenjoino, aí me parece uma outra pergunta. Eu sugiro abrir uma nova pergunta sobre como deve ser feita esta configuração do `.ebextensions`, pois entendi na sua pergunta original que sua dúvida era da localização do arquivo e como colocar ele na aplicação com Spring Boot.

Comment: Devido a complexidade encontrada e falta de tempo para resolver a questão, acabei optando por utilizar um load balance. Desta maneira foi simples configurar e ficou funcional. Agora é aguardar pra verificar os custos envolvidos. De qualquer sorte, agradeço a atenção.

Answer (score 1):

Depois de algumas pesquisas e realização desse procedimento manualmente, segue o passo a passo para subir uma aplicação Spring Boot com https no Elastic Beanstalk de apenas uma instancia, assim como o @DuilioBenjoino disse nos comentários ele conseguiu realizar o procedimento com o Load Balance uma vez que AWS automatiza a inclusão do certificado SSL deixando tudo mais simples, por outro lado é um pouco mais complexo quando não temos o Load Balance.

Essa descrição e um compilado da documentação oficial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-java.html

De acordo com o link oficial para habilitar https em um ambiente de Java SE que é o caso do Spring Boot é necessário que seja empacotado junto com bytecode uma pasta chamada .ebextensions essa pasta deve possuir 3 arquivos, são eles:

1. .ebextensions/https-instance.config
2. .ebextensions/https-instance-single.config
3. .ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/https.conf

Uma importante observação sobre os dois primeiros arquivos, eu tive um pouco de dificuldade de gera-los corretamente porque é possível envia-los em dois formatos YAML ou JSON como a documentação recomenda YAML pelo fato de ser mais legível foi esse o formato que eu escolhi porém eu nunca tinha utilizado e não me atentei a questão da formatação algo que esta muito claro na documentação e que deve ser seguido para o perfeito funcionamento, "sempre use espaços para recuar as chaves em diferentes níveis de aninhamento" isso significa que deve ser utilizado um editor de textos que usa espaços para fazer a formatação do arquivo no meu caso eu utilizei o Intellij que faz isso como padrão para arquivos YAML.

Quando criar um novo arquivo no Intellij com a extensão .config sera perguntado qual o editor que deseja associar esse arquivo, associe ao YAML.

[image: Como associar o arquivo .config a editor YAML no Intellij]

Segue a documentação para mais informações sobre os arquivos de configuração:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html

O primeiro arquivo é referente ao certificado SSL, sua chave privada e um comando para reiniciar o nginx. Não vou entrar em detalhes da geração desse certificado auto-assinado pois esta bem detalhado [aqui](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-ssl.html) ao final da geração do certificado existiram dois arquivos server.crt e privatekey.pem o certificado e a chave respectivamente. Coloque o conteúdo do certificado dentro de content no caminho /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt e o conteúdo da chave dentro de content no caminho /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key ficando dessa forma: (muita atenção a questão da formatação)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O segundo arquivo é referente ao grupo de segurança da instância como estamos configurando um ambiente de instância única essa configuração e obrigatória para adicionar uma regra ao grupo dessa instância que serve para habilitar o tráfego na porta 443, apenas copie o código para o arquivo como esta na documentação.

O terceiro arquivo é referente a configuração do nginx, este é um proxy reverso que vem por padrão no ambiente do Elastic Beanstalk, ele possui uma configuração padrão mas para habilitar https e necessário substitui-la. Apenas copie o código para o arquivo como esta na documentação substituindo o valor de app_port pelo número da porta do seu aplicativo.

Com os 3 arquivos criados seu projeto Spring Boot deve se parecer com isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O projeto esta pronto para ser enviado ao ElasticBeanstalk com https habilitado o problema e que o jar padrão que é gerado pelo plugin do spring boot não contem a pasta .ebextensions, para gerar um jar que contenha essa pasta é necessário assim como o @Dherik comentou na sua resposta adicionar um novo plugin, fiz exatamente como ele colocou com apenas uma mudança na tag zip, propriedade destfile coloquei no final do nome AWS para diferenciar o jar spring boot do específico para a AWS.

destfile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-AWS.jar"

Segue o link para o projeto de exemplo criado para tirar possíveis dúvidas:
https://github.com/pedrobacchini/EnableHTTPSElasticBeanstalk

Em relação a utilização do certificado gerado pela aws acredito ser necessário copiar o certificado e chave privada assim como descrevi para o certificado auto-assinado e deve funcionar normalmente, não tenho certeza pois não testei esse caso pois o certificado auto-assinado já foi suficiente.